# Circular Import Error in Flask and Flask_SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-import

My folder structure looks like -
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kMRH.png)

I am trying to write my code in a modular way but running into circular imports.
I am working on ORM models and a basic login/register user scenario in flask.

My code looks like -

```
*app/__init__.py*

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "..."
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()

from app import routes 

def get_session():
    return db.session()
```

crud/crud_user.py

```
from app.model import User
from app import get_session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

session = get_session()
def save_user_detail(user: User):
    # make use of session here
    pass
```

Error -

```
$ python runserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Projects\Modular\server-side\app\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from app import routes
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Projects\Modular\server-side\app\routes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from crud.crud_user import get_user, save_user_detail
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Projects\Modular\server-side\crud\crud_user.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import get_session
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_session' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the line `from app import routes` in `app/__init__.py` is the issue. Because during the initialisation of your `app/__init__.py` file you actually import `routes` from that `__init__` file itself which won't work

But more generally, creating the Flask app and putting other global objects in the `__init__.py` file is non-conventional I believe. Usually the `__init__.py` file is used to provide alternative names for modules in your package and not for holding global objects.

Better is to store those things in a module called `app.py` or something so they don't get imported every time `from app import foo` is called

Comment: Also don't name variables with the same name as your import.

Comment: How to use the `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` in crud_user.py file to create a reference ? Do we need to import it ? Because then it gives the circular import error

Comment: @Martin If I do not import routes in `app.py` then what is the alternative ? Isn't it that `routes.py` should be imported in `app.py` ?

Comment: Does this example help: https://github.com/sriramveeraghanta/flask-sqlalchemy-blogger-example/tree/master/blogger

Comment: [link](https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-application-structure) I found this really helpful.